# What is the word for "separate into 2 parts"?

Tags: word-request, terminology

I'm looking for a word which basically means "separate an object into two parts", for example, boy and girl (gender), vegan and non-vegan, extrovert and introvert.
I remembered that I have read that word somewhere, but cannot recall it now. It likes "bipolar" or "bilingual".

Comment: Try *distinguish* or *sort* for something more conversational.

Comment: If you put those words you mention in separate columns, you are not separating an object into two parts. You are classifying words in two categories...

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of *bisect*

> [bisect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bisect)
>
> - to divide into two usually equal parts:
>     The new road would bisect a designated historic district.
> - geometry to divide something into two congruent (= exactly equal) parts
>
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

However, I'm not confident that it fits the examples you gave. *Bisect* is used with physical things, or, in particular, geometry.

You might consider [categorize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/categorize) or [classify](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classify) for the given examples.

Comment: "Divide" itself would be proper word to use in the sense of "separating out into 2 or more parts".

Comment: Yes, I also thought of "divide". But I was thinking that fits better if he physically wants to separate a group of people, and I'm not sure that's the case. Also, "segregate", though that's a little complicated.

Answer (score 0):

To separate into two parts is to take something single and split it in half. It's normally used in an empirical sense—splitting something physical into two smaller pieces.

But when you are talking about *bipolar* and *bilingual*, you're using it in a figurative sense. If I spoke two languages, I would still be the same person—not two people. Perhaps you could consider me as have two *parts*, but it wouldn't be the same thing as pouring half a glass of water into another glass and ending up with two half-glasses.

It's probably more accurate to say that if if I exhibit two different things at once (like a coin has two sides), what I represent is **duality** or **dualism**.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*dualism*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dualism):

> **2** : the quality or state of being dual or of having a dual nature

And **dual**:

> (1/2)
>   **1** *of grammatical number* : denoting reference to two
>   // a *dual* pronoun
>   **2 a** : consisting of two parts or elements or having two like parts : DOUBLE
>   // families with *dual* incomes
>   // held *dual* citizenship in France and the U.S.
>   // a *dual* function
>   // a *dual* exhaust system
>   **b** : having a double character or nature
>
> (2/2)
>   *linguistics*
>   **1** : the dual (see DUAL entry 1 sense 1) number of a language
>   **2** : a linguistic form in the dual

This can also be used in the sense of the juxtaposition of opposites that aren't necessarily part of the same actual thing or person but of an idea:

> // the *dualism* of human nature
>   // the *dualism* of good and evil

---

Alternately, if you're looking for a word that *looks* the same as *bipolar* and *bilingual*, you might be thinking of [**bifurcate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bifurcate):

> : to cause to divide into two branches or parts
>   // *bifurcate* a beam of light
>   // The stream *bifurcates* into two narrow channels.

However, again, this is not normally used in a figurative sense, and wouldn't be used to describe the dual nature of the ideas of *boy/girl, vegan/non-vegan*, or *extrovert/introvert*.

Answer (score 0):

**Dichotomize:** to divide into two parts, classes, or groups

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomize))

"Dichotomize" works well for instances like the ones listed by the original poster because the word implies a defined opposition and creates two distinct parties, introducing the *duality* mentioned by previous commenters.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Please have a look at our [referencing guidelines](/help/referencing).